# I am having problem with appendChild() while creating new element using createElement("ul")

Tags: javascript, html

I am having problem creating UL and LI below the P tag. Can someone take a look at my codes below? The javascript is returning the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: thisIsQuizContainer.appendChild is not a function

Changing it to document.body.appendChild() will create the UL in the body. How do i create the UL inside the div quizMainContainer?

This is the HTML:

```
<div id="quizMainContainer">
  <h2>Question 1 of 3:</h2>
  <p id="quizQuestion"></p>

  <!-- create UL here -->

</div>
```

This is my Javascript.

```
var ulCreate = document.createElement("ul");
var thisIsQuizContainer = document.querySelectorAll('#quizMainContainer');

function render(questionIndex) {
    // Clears existing data 
    questionsDiv.innerHTML = "";
    ulCreate.innerHTML = "";
    thisIsQuizContainer.innerHTML = "";

    // For loops to loop through all info in array
    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
        // Appends question title only
        var userQuestion = questions[questionIndex].title;
        var userChoices = questions[questionIndex].choices;
        questionsDiv.textContent = userQuestion;
    }
    // New for each for question choices
    userChoices.forEach(function (newItem) {
        var listItem = document.createElement("li");
        listItem.textContent = newItem;
        thisIsQuizContainer.appendChild(ulCreate);
        ulCreate.appendChild(listItem);
        listItem.addEventListener("click", (compare));
    })
}
```

Comment: `thisIsQuizContainer` is a NodeList, not an Element - use `document.querySelector('#quizMainContainer');` instead

Comment: who is calling `render`

Comment: Add `[0]` after `thisIsQuizContainer`. `thisIsQuizContainer[0]`. Or just call by the id `document.getElementById('quizMainContainer')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.querySelectorAll('#quizMainContainer') // nodelist [{},{},{}]
```

which select list of elements from the dom, I suggest you use

```
document.getElementById('#quizMainContainer') // node element
```

Comment: Is that hash `#` necessary to getElementById? @vamshi

Comment: @Rafv, you need to use '#' for selecting an element with its id attribute. and '.' for selecting a class attribute.